# Why is cycle stopping?

Tags: c++

I have a program with bool function issquare, which code don't need for you for my question. I have iterative variable T, which is response for how many times I will put squarsized's time string. But after first input of strings programs stop, at T=1, and don't go to next iteration. Why?

```
int main(){
    int T;
    std::string line;
    std::cin>>T;
    int squaresize;
    int** arr=new int*[30];
    for(int d=0; d<30; d++){
        arr[d]=new int[30];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
        for (int d=0; d<30; d++){
            for(int d1=0; d<30; d++){
                arr[d][d1]=0;
            }
        }
        std::cin>>squaresize;
        for(int j=0; i<squaresize; i++){
            std::cin>>line;
            for(int a=0; a<squaresize; a++){
                if (line[a]=='#'){
                    arr[j][a]=1;
                }
            }
        }   
        if (issquare(arr, squaresize)==true){
            std::cout<<"Case #"<<i+1<<": YES";
        }
        else{
            std::cout<<"Case #"<<i+1<<": NO";
        }
        std::cout<<T;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
std::cin>>line;
```

Try

```
getline(std::cin, line);
```

`operator>>` doesn't read an entire line, only until the first whitespace.

Comment: @ratkke: No, it reads until the first whitespace, which could be `\n` or could be a space, tab, `\r`, and so on.  Whichever comes first.

Comment: So, for my problem - >> is perfectly ok. But my reading of line not in the main loop, so main loop is not depending on input line. But the main loop stops, and this is the question

Comment: @ratkke: You need to explain your program a lot better.  What input are you typing in?  What output is the program producing?  With no prompts, do you even know what the program is waiting for you to type?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of j you are comparing and incrementing i, which is also used by the outer loop:

```
for(int j=0; i<squaresize; i++){
    std::cin>>line;
    for(int a=0; a<squaresize; a++){
        if (line[a]=='#'){
            arr[j][a]=1;
        }
    }
}
```

In the future (and with possibly more complex programs), learning how to use of a debugger can really help you to locate such bugs. Your problem was that the outmost loop executed less than T times:

```
for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
```

Since the value of T is constant, something must be modifying i inside the loop. An easy way to debug this would be using a debugger to find out where the variable is changed. In Visual Studio this can be done by breaking and adding a data breakpoint from Debug -> New Breakpoint -> New Data Breakpoint -> Address: &i